# Unable to play a .AVI video inside my Rich Text editor field, "Media Failed to load.. This file in a format that is not recognized"

Tags: 2013, development, html, video, media-streaming

I have sharepoint enterprise server 2013. And I am working on a discussion board list inside my team site collection 2013. the team site collection does not have the publishing infrastructure features enabled. and i want to allow our users to upload videos inside the announcement item's Rick Text Editor field. so i follow these steps:-

1. I added a new List of type "Asset Library".
2. users will be uploading video to the Asset Library.
3. then they can copy the Embed Code,and paste it inside the announcement body field.

now this worked well for the `.mp4` files, but when i try this for a .avi file i got this error:-

[image]

so can anyone advice what are the supported files for Videos inside sharepoint 2013? and can i fix the problem with `.avi` files? or sharepoint does not support these types of Videos ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as per my knowledge In HTML5, there are 3 supported video formats: MP4, WebM, and Ogg.
WebM and Ogg are two much newer file types related to HTML5 video, 
I have tested only for MP4.

Please see below link for more details,

•   http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

•   http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/html5-videos-things-you-need-to-know/

Comment: so can i conclude from your reply , that sharepoint 2013 follow the  HTML-5 standards for the supported Video file formats ??

Comment: The  browser you are using either chrome/edge/Mozilla or whatever to open the SharePoint portal it is supporting HTML 5. so i can say in simple term - yes.

Comment: so if i want to play/embed videos inside my Rich text Editor field then i can have the videos in these formats only MP4, WebM, and Ogg ??

Comment: yes, I have worked on SharePoint Online for the same kind of issue.

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it helped you :)